# Facets doesnt work on FOSElasticaBundle

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

```
if(count($priceRange)){
    $facets = new \Elastica\Facet\Range('price');
    $facets->setField('price');

    foreach ($min as $key => $value) {
        $facets->addRange(intval($min[$key])*100, intval($max[$key])*100);
    }

    $facets->setGlobal(false);
    $query->addFacet($facets);
}
```

This doesn't work for me, I am trying to search on two ways.

Like this:

```
$client = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.client')
$searcher = new \Elastica\Search($client)
$esResultSet = $searcher->search($query , 500)
$arrayOfResults = $esResultSet->getResults()
$facets = $esResultSet->getFacets()
```

Or like this

```
$resultSet = $finder->find($query, 500)
```

Neither of this works. Why my facet range doesn't work?

Comment: Don't use the fos finder. This won't help you get facets. Can you post a bit more code, where `$query` gets assigned.

Comment: Sure I can here is more code:

Comment: Add it as an update! Not an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is more code:

```
 $boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Bool();
    $fieldText = new \Elastica\Query\Text();
    $fieldText->setFieldQuery('name', $keyword);
    $fieldText->setFieldParam('name', 'analyzer', 'my_analyzer');
    $boolQuery->addMust($fieldText);

    $fieldText = new \Elastica\Query\Text();
    $fieldText->setFieldQuery('description', $keyword);
    $fieldText->setFieldParam('description', 'analyzer', 'my_analyzer');
    $boolQuery->addShould($fieldText);

    $fieldTerms = new \Elastica\Query\Terms();
    $fieldTerms->setTerms('country_id', $countryArray);
    $boolQuery->addMust($fieldTerms);

    $fieldTerms = new \Elastica\Query\Terms();
    $fieldTerms->setTerms('taxon_ids', $themeArray);
    $boolQuery->addMust($fieldTerms);

    $query->setSort(array("price" => array("order" => "asc")));
```

Comment: Firstly, are you actually using `$boolQuery`? You construct it, but I never see it used. Secondly, `text` query is deprecated, use a `match` query. Thirdly, I asked to see where `$query` gets assigned, please help me help you!

Comment: Here is query assigned
$query = Query::create($boolQuery);

Comment: That's not what deprecated means... [Have a read of the official docs please](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/text-query/). I'm trying to help you!

Comment: give me example for match query, instead of text?

Comment: I don't know, why it's not working. Are you sure about this line: `$facets->addRange(intval($min[$key])*100, intval($max[$key])*100);`

Comment: Also you seem to be able to use the other types of query, I'm sure you can figure out how to construct a `match` query!

Comment: regarding line above , I find somwhere this as example long time ago and now it doesn't work, I test it with hardcoded values and it still doesn't work...